# Imputing MCAR Data

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

In practice, MCAR data cant be imputed.

I have a data set which spans 2 years of individuals who joined a website.

During the past 4 months a survey was given to individuals registering on the site.

So I have individuals who had the survey over the past 4 months and null values for the survey question responses for individuals who joined the preceding 20 months.

I believe the missing values are MCAR and therefore shouldn't be imputed.

Or should they?

How do I handle missing values in this case so I can make use of the survey question responses in predictive modeling?

Comment: Your statement MCAR data can't be imputed is false. In fact, MCAR data is the easiest to impute, even simple random imputation does a reasonable job under the MCAR assumption. I think you are misunderstanding what MCAR missingness is.

Comment: you are probably right.  But does that mean my pre survey nulls are MCAR or MAR?  Either way,  is it appropriate to impute?

Comment: It depends. Is the fact that someone joined in the preceding 20 months as opposed to the current 4 months related to your variable of interest? If so you have MNAR. Is it related to the some other auxiliary variable? Then it’s MAR. Related to neither? Then you have MCAR. Any of these is imputable, the quality of the imputation however will depend on which missingness mechanism you actually have